# Поддержка формата webp в Firefox?

Tags: изображения, firefox, webp

Общеизвестная проблема о том, что лиса не поддерживает формат webp(изображения). Как фиксить?

Comment: Не использовать webp?

Comment: такая себе альтернатива

Comment: Лучше всех остальных альтернатив

Answer (score 0):

Уже вышел Firefox 65, 29.01.2019 начнется обновление браузеров.
Вот тут будет список изменений, https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/65.0/releasenotes/ Должна добавиться поддержка WebP. Но нужно ещё подождать около месяца, пока основная часть пользователей обновится.

А если нужны решения специальные, то у самого с этим проблема. Знаю, что некоторые умудряются подключать их через тег . Кто-то приписывает правило через .htaccess. Третий вариант, за вас это сделает сервер. Так же необходимо прописать правила для выполнения этой задачи. И четвёртый - через скрипты на сайте, через определение движка браузера клиента и подбора подходящей картинки по формату. Но повторюсь, пока мне не удалось добиться результатов.